# Isekai anime where the protagonist can recreate any weapon he has touched, and the side character has control over chains

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

There is an isekai anime, where they enter a game staged in their own world. The protagonist can recreate any weapon he has touched and the side-character can control chains. There is also a character who is a sniper with the ability to see into the near future.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, did you watch it on TV or online? If on TV, then in which country and on which channel, if you recall?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[Darwin's Game](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11405390/)*** (2020).

From IMDB:

> **Darwin's Game focuses on 17-year old Kaname Sudou, who accepts an online invitation from a friend to play a mobile game called Darwin's Game. He had no idea that the game involves a fight between the two players and you might actually die both in the game and in real life.** To win the fight, players are given a Sigil, an evolutionary ability that varies from player to player and only the most skillful players will be able to clear the game and survive. Kaname determines to clear the game, find the creators of the game and take revenge upon them.

[The Wikipedia page for the manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin%27s_Game) says the following about the male lead, Kaname Sudō:

> **His Sigil "The Fire God's Hammer", allows him to recreate weapons and other simple objects he has touched before,** in addition to modifying them to his will, although this exhausts him easily and the objects created will disappear should he lose consciousness.

The same page says the following about the female lead, Shuka Karino:

> **Her Sigil "Princess of Thorn" allows her to control wire-like objects, which she utilises to wield spiked chains.**

And it says the following about a third character, Rein Kashiwagi:

> **Her Sigil "Laplace's Demon" allows her to calculate physical vectors and knowledge to such an extent to the point where she can visualise the near future,** although her ability can be countered by moving in manners that surpass physical limits and conventional predictions. While she would normally prefer to run away, **she can fight by combining her ability with a sniper's firepower.**

Comment: Thank you for the help... greatly appreciated!!!